# How to launch multiple dispatchs

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

First of all, give thanks for reading my question and try to help me and apologize for my English.

I would like to launch multiple dispatchs on redux.
I'm using redux and redux-thunk.

I have a method called deleteLayer which I want launch first deleteLayerFromMapBox and when finishes, launch next dispatch that call method called deleteFromRedux.

Here is my code:

```
static deleteLayer(layer) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(this.deleteLayerFromMapBox(layer));
        dispatch(this.deleteFromRedux(layer));
    }
}

static deleteLayerFromMapBox(layer) {
    const mapLayers = [... AxisStore.getStore().getState().map.mapGLlayers];
    const ids = mapLayers.map(l => l.id);
    const index = ids.indexOf(layer.id);
    mapLayers[index].redraw = false;

    return {
        type: MapTypeConstants.SET_MAP_LAYERS,
        payload: mapLayers
    };
}

static deleteFromRedux(layer) {
    const mapLayers = [... AxisStore.getStore().getState().map.mapGLlayers];
    const ids = mapLayers.map(l => l.id);
    const index = ids.indexOf(layer.id);
    mapLayers.splice(index, 1);

    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: MapTypeConstants.SET_MAP_LAYERS,
            payload: mapLayers
        });
    };
}
```

Problem:

The problem is that first I have to change property redraw to false to remove it from MapComponent that shows on navigator all layers. And later remove it from array of redux with splice.
If combine two methods it crashes.

So I want to know of two make that when finish deleteLayerFromMapbox call next method deleteFromRedux.

```
{this.props.mapGLlayers &&
    this.props.mapGLlayers.map((l, index) => {
        return (
            <div key={index}>
                {l.name && <Source id={"sourceId_" + l.id} tileJsonSource={l.source} />}
                {l.redraw && l.redraw === true &&
                    <Layer type={l.type} id={l.id} sourceId={l.name ? "sourceId_" + l.id : l['source'] ? l['source'] : undefined}
                    sourceLayer={l['source-layer'] ? l['source-layer'] : undefined}
                    filter={l.filter ? l.filter : undefined}
                    paint={l.paint ? l.paint : undefined}
                    layout={l.layout ? l.layout : undefined}
                    before={l.before ? l.before : undefined}
                />}
            </div>
        );
    })
}
```

MY REDUCER REDUCED:

```
export default function MapReducer(state = initialStateApp, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case MapTypeConstants.SET_MAP_LAYERS: {
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            mapGLlayers: action.payload
        });
    }
    default:
       return state;
}
```

Comment: I think you should combine the logics in `deleteLayerFromMapBox` and `deleteFromRedux` unless you are using it in someother place separately.

Comment: What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: Its no possible combine logics because deleteLayerFromMapbox change the redraw property to false to remove it from mapbox. To delete it from screen and later remove it from array of redux.

Comment: Why do you need two actions for that ? Why don't you just update the reducer with the first action ?

Comment: I updated my question with methods that change redraw property to false and in updateBefore change redraw to true.
How can update redraw property for each layer on reducer, Pcriulan?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your `redraw` property, if you don't want `react` to render it, just don't put remove it from the array in the first place, no ?

Comment: I  use redraw property to render a layer using react-mapbox-gl.
To redraw in l.redraw has to change true to false to remove from mapbox array, with contains layers that are rendered. So I created a lateral menu with layers and if you click on move.. that layer move 1 position top or down. But also, change position I need redraw it. 
And to remove it I have to change redraw to false to remove automatically from array of react-mapbox-gl and later remove from the array of layers that I've on redux.